# Php Mysql echo, referencing syntax help (echo, if/else)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, reference

I have two tables in my database:
1.) members (id,username,email,password,salt,tier) <-tier is a user's security clearance level.
2.) opwire (category,contents,date,userid,seclevel)  <-opwire stores user submitted data, userid is a number that references the user who just submitted data to opwire. Seclevel is how high of a security clearance level a user needs to see that particular submitted data.

I then have a php file called get_opwire.php (shown below) that pulls the info from opwire and lists it in a table.  What I want to accomplish is restricting/allowing information by referencing tier vs seclevel.

For instance suppose opwire looks like this:

-Category / contents / date / userid / seclevel

*-Enemy Location/Tank behind courthouse/today/1/5*

*-Item Location/Bazooka in trashcan/today/1/2*

If Bob is logged in and he has tier 3 access, he would see

*-Enemy Location/**ACCESS DENIED**/today/Admin*

*-Item Location/Bazooka in trashcan/today/Admin*

(Admin is just the user who submitted the data, ie userid.) So it's really only the contents area echo that needs to reflect this change. I thought about using a nested if/while with the >= principle (if Bob's tier number is >= seclevel, echo contents, else echo access denied,) but honestly modding what I have here to do this syntax wise is a bit over my head.

Would anyone be able to help?  Here's get_opwire.php:

```
<?php 

include_once 'functions.php';
include_once 'db_connect.php';
sec_session_start();

if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","mylogin","mypassword","mysqldatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


function getColor($strOption)
{
   switch ($strOption)
   {
       case "Enemy Location":
       return "#cbae80";

       case "Item Location":
       return "#e59350";

       case "Another Category etc":
       return "#b7aaa4";

    }
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT opwire.*,members.username FROM opwire 
          LEFT JOIN members on opwire.userid=members.id order by date DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Contents</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
<th>Operative</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font size=1 color='".getColor($row['category'])."'> " . $row['category'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size=1 color=#e4d6b5>" . $row['contents'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size=1 color=silver>" . $row['date'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size=1 color=gold>" . $row['username'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

} else {
   echo 'Access to this area requires security clearance. <br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Bazooka in trashcan is just an example.  Please don't let it deter you from helping me out here.